# Svelte - switching between two input values using a checkbox

Tags: input, svelte

I'm new to svelte and I am trying to figure out how to change a default value of an input when a checkbox is checked and also use this changed value in a calculation.

The code I have works:

```
 <label> {#if yes}
SI Units to US Units
{:else}
    US Units to SI units
{/if}
<input type=checkbox bind:checked={yes}>
</label>


{#if yes}
<input bind:value={siValue}>        
{:else}
<input bind:value={usValue}>        
{/if}

{#if yes}
<span>{((siValue / factor)).toFixed(2)}</span>
{:else}
<span>{((usValue * factor)).toFixed(2)}</span>
{/if}
```

What I would like to do is use just one input and change the default value but also be able to manually change the input value as well, but I'm having trouble getting it to work. The value changes but when I try and change the numeric value manually, the calculation does not work.

Here is that code:

```
 <input value={yes ? siValue : usValue} on:input="{e => setUnitVal(e.target.value)}">


<script>
let yes = false;
let siValue = '';
let usValue = '';

function setUnitVal(value) {
    siValue = +value;
    usValue = +value;
}   

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edited after talking in the comments*

Since assigning to an object in an array triggers a re-render, you could conditionally calculate the new `siValue` and `usValue` for a given `unit` based on the `yes` flag, and update the values for that unit. That'll let you update both the SI and US values as the user types, so they can freely switch which value goes in the inputs.

```html
<script>
  let yes = false;

  const units = [{
    "factor": "6.614",
    "siValue": "66",
    "usValue": "10"
  }, {
    "factor": "97.95",
    "siValue": "100",
    "usValue": "1"
  }];

  function setUnitVal(value, index) {
    const { factor } = units[index];

    units[index].siValue = yes ? value : (value * factor).toFixed(2);
    units[index].usValue = yes ? (value / factor).toFixed(2) : value;
  }
</script>

<label>
  {#if yes}SI Units to US Units{:else}US Units to SI units{/if}
  <input type="checkbox" bind:checked={yes} />
</label>

{#each unitValues as { usValue, siValue, factor}, i}    
  <div>
    <input
      value={yes ? siValue : usValue}
      on:input={e => setUnitVal(e.target.value, i)} />

    {#if yes}
      <span>{usValue}</span>
    {:else}
      <span>{siValue}</span>
    {/if}
  </div>
{/each}
```

---

If you wanted to be able to revert to defaults, then you could clone that `units` array on load, and reset to the original values at will, like so:

```html
<script>
  import _ from 'lodash'

  const units = [...];

  let unitValues = [];

  function resetUnitValues() {
    unitValues = _.cloneDeep(units);
  }

  resetUnitValues();
</script>

...

<button on:click={resetUnitValues}>Clear</button>
```

Here's all that in the Svelte REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/aed32ef30b02448aafd173e0baf681b0?version=3.12.1

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the code. Not quite. My main issue is getting the inputs to work when the value is changed manually after the initial value is set. Here is your Svelte REPL with some data added: https://svelte.dev/repl/c1ecefa1e1ac4efe86ca0c0da8b476ef?version=3.12.1

Comment: Also, the `siValue` and `usValue` are not calculated values.  So I'm not sure about this code: `function setUnitVal(value) {
    // Do the conditional logic here
    siValue = yes ? value : value * factor;
    usValue = yes ? value / factor : value;
  }`

Comment: Ah okay, I think I see. So you want to track many values at once, starting with some default values.

Comment: Given that list of units, would it work to update the siValue and usValue of the updated field, like in this REPL? https://svelte.dev/repl/aed32ef30b02448aafd173e0baf681b0?version=3.12.1

Also, I'm doing the calculated update so if for instance you're in SI mode, the siValue gets updated to be the same as the input, and the usValue gets updated to be the equivalent.

Comment: Hmm, not seeing the calculation  update when the input is changed. I may be confusing you. Here is my work in progress. It works except for the first time one selects an input and types a number. For some reason it updates the input below the focused one.When I reselect, it works.  https://svelte.dev/repl/9e187bb2a1014df88477408c0fc3f782?version=3.12.1

Comment: Oh sorry! I forgot to hit the save button on that last REPL. Try it again, if you would.

Comment: That works. Slightly different than what I was thinking but could be useful in real world use. Would need to have a reset button to set to original values but other wise working with less code. Thanks. I'll see how it works in my current code. If you want to edit the code ( so others will see the final version), then I will go ahead and accept your answer.

Comment: @Macsupport glad that was helpful! Added a piece about resetting, in case that's useful

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do the same. You can use the JS label syntax `$:` to make the values of `usValue` and `siValue` reactive. We will not place `$:` directly on `usValue` and `siValue` since it will create a cyclical dependency since `usValue` depends on `siValue` and vice versa. Instead we will place it on the `yes` variable and conditionally assign `usValue` and `siValue`.

Then in the template, all we need to do is bind the input `value` and `span` to their respective variables while the JS label syntax takes care of the calculation for us.

```
<script>
    let yes = false;
    let factor = 1.2;
    let siValue = '';
    let usValue = '';
    $: yes ? usValue = (siValue / factor).toFixed(2) : siValue = (usValue * factor).toFixed(2);
</script>

<label>
    {#if yes}
        SI Units to US Units
    {:else}
        US Units to SI units
    {/if}
    <input type=checkbox bind:checked={yes}>
</label>

{#if yes}
    <input bind:value={siValue}>
    <span>{usValue}</span>
{:else}
    <input bind:value={usValue}>
    <span>{siValue}</span>
{/if}
```

Here is an example on the Svelte [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/69e7206ac9f24588bd2ee061988a2348?version=3.12.1).

Comment: Thanks! Out of curiosity, could this method be used if I wanted to use 2 inputs (and not using the checkbox at all), one with the `usValue` and the other the `siValue` so that changing one, changes the others value and vice versa?

Comment: You can change the condition. Instead of using `yes`, create another variable, say `unitType` and on the `input` on `focus` set `unitType` to `si` or `us` based on which `input` it is. Then update the condition to `unitType === 'si' ? usValue = (siValue / factor).toFixed(2) : siValue = (usValue * factor).toFixed(2);`